# Add custom http header with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, http-headers

I'm not able to add a custom HTTP header in the GET queries in my angularJS application.
I'm trying to add a custom header like
toto : testing value

into a http get call in AngularJS.

I tried the following:

```
            $http.get('http://www.google.com',{headers : {'toto' : 'test value'}});
```

I also tried a solution using `$http.default.header.common` but it leads to the same result and the result is:

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers: toto
```

It modifies the value of the Access-Control-Request-Headers ?
What do I misunderstand here?
Any idea of how I can achieve that?

Comment: Call your URL service instead of 'www.google.com' and try use the example of API Reference (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

`var req = {
 method: "GET",
 url: "http://example.com",
 headers: {
   "Content-Type": "plain/text"
 }
}

$http(req).then(function(){...}, function(){...});`

Comment: I just created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Puigcerber/Lz3buztt/) with your  code and it works as expected. So you are missing something else.